# Of the various methods of decaffeinating coffee, which is the safest?

Tags: health, decaffeinated

There are various methods of decaffeinating coffee beans:

- **Swiss Water method**<sup>**[1](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-is-decaffeinated-coffee-made)**</sup>
- **Co<sub>2</sub> Process**<sup>**[1](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-is-decaffeinated-coffee-made)**</sup>
- **Roselius Proccess**<sup>**[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decaffeination#Roselius_process)**</sup>
- **Direct Method**<sup>**[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decaffeination#Direct_method)**</sup>
- **Indirect Method**<sup>**[4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decaffeination#Indirect_method)**</sup>
- **Triglyceride process**<sup>**[5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decaffeination#Triglyceride_process)**</sup>

Of these various methods, **are any of them (potentially) harmful to humans?** Be it short-term or long-term? Which is the safest?

Answer (score 5):

Swiss Water process is the best because it's the most natural and has the best percentage of decaffeination. However, none of the processes are dangerous, I repeat, none. Unless you consume the decaffeinating solvents somehow, that's a different case. -.-

Sourced from my previous answer at [How is decaffeinated coffee made?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-is-decaffeinated-coffee-made?lq=1)

Comment: +1 here and in your other answer simply because of the included image