# Which decaffeination process changes the flavor of the coffee the least?

Tags: flavor, decaffeinated

There are many decaffeination methods available:

- Swiss Water method
- CO<sub>2</sub> Process
- Roselius Process
- Direct Method
- Indirect Method
- Triglyceride process

(Thanks to [Mooz](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/users/179/mooz) for providing the list I found in his [related question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/208/of-the-various-methods-of-decaffeinating-coffee-which-is-the-safest).)

Of these various methods, which changes the flavor of the coffee the least?

**Bonus question: can I buy unroasted beans of that kind?** (That's what I'm really after!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the article [here](http://legacy.sweetmarias.com/library/content/caffeine-health-and-eco-concerns) and some brief experience with roasting decaf myself, I'd agree that the methylene chloride method seems to produce more flavorful beans.  That being said it's hard to make a direct comparison due to the difficulties in getting a single batch of beans and getting them processed for decaf at multiple facilities.  I think your best bet is to find a green coffee seller that you trust and see what they have to offer.