# Decaffeinated Coffee Beans

Tags: beans, bean-varieties, decaffeinated, bean-to-cup

I recently bought a bean-to-cup coffee machine and I drink a lot more coffee than I should. As decaffeinated coffee would do me good, I was hoping that there was a decaf coffee bean. I would like to use the bean grinding function of my machine but I do not want the caffeine.

I have looked online and can't find any, but I am sure that someone will have tried to make a decaf coffee bean. Is there such a thing?

Comment: If you are in the UK, PACT Coffee do some nice decaffee coffee and you can request it unground (or if you wanted in the future, ground for a secific brewing method).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There's no strain of coffee bean that has no caffeine when it is grown, but you can find whole-bean, decaffeinated coffee.** "Decaffeinated" coffee has been treated to have most of the caffeine removed. Decaffeination is done when the beans are still whole, so you can certainly find whole-bean, decaffeinated coffee (though I suppose decaffeination could also be done after grinding). The decaffeination process is often done with whole, green (not-yet-roasted) beans, which are subsequently roasted (still whole). Most places will sell whole-bean, decaf coffee -- local coffee roasters, coffee shops, markets, mail order from the usual suspects... [Starbucks](http://store.starbucks.co.uk/decaf-espresso-roast-fairtrade-certified/011037989,en_GB,pd.html?&srule=Featured&start=0&sz=12&cgid=whole-bean&prefn1=decaffeinated&prefv1=decaffeinated), [illy](http://www.illy.com/wps/wcm/connect/en/coffee-at-home/whole-bean-coffee), [Lavazza](http://www.lavazza.co.uk/uk/at-home/blends/caffe-decaffeinato.html), [Peets](http://www.peets.com/decaf-house-blend.html), ... Look for "whole bean decaf".

For more on the subject of decaf coffee, see [this question about how decaf coffee beans are produced](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-is-decaffeinated-coffee-made) and another question about the fact that [decaf coffee still has a little caffeine in it](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-is-decaffeinated-coffee-made).

The concept of "half-caf" coffee has become popular, mixing part decaffeinated beans with part regular (not-decaffeinated) beans, which might be a good option in your case to reduce (but not eliminate) the caffeine. These half-and-half blends are also available from retailers.

Answer (score 0):

Swiss Water Decaf beans are your best option, and also the best starting point. Reason being, is that it so good! But I would say that as I'm a supplier, but I also say it because I have not found anything else that is comparable for flavour and cost. Ultimately it will come down to your taste buds but if start here then at the very least you have a high benchmark. Checkout the video on how they treat the beans here: https://youtu.be/fhz9njRLbl0

Answer (score 0):

While I don't believe it is possible to buy these yet, scientists have discovered a strain of Coffea Arabica which naturally has very little caffeine.

https://www.theguardian.com/science/2004/jun/24/food.research

Comment: That article is over a decade old.  If it hasn't been brought to market yet, I surely wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 0):

There are several online stores selling decaf whole beans.
To name but a few:

- [Has Bean Coffee](https://www.hasbean.co.uk/collections/decaffeinated)
- [Horsham Coffee Roaster](https://www.horshamcoffeeroaster.co.uk/collections/coffee)
- Union
- Square Mile Coffee Roasters

Answer (score 0):

Cafe Justo has whole bean decaf and 50%/50% coffee. https://www.justcoffee.org/
They see coffee by the pound, not 12 oz.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to go to a specialty shop or buy online.  If you have a large chain grocery store with a decent coffee section, you're likely to find some decaffeinated whole bean choices.  At a chain grocery store, there is a very limited audience for whole bean coffee, and an even smaller audience for decaffeinated whole bean, so there won't be nearly the selection of offerings.  The choices tend to be varieties that are popular in the general consumer market, although a store with a good coffee section may surprise you.

In the US, you're likely to find Eight O'clock Original Blend if the store carries any decaf whole bean.  There is also frequently a decaf Columbian whole bean.  If your area is served by certain grocery chains with generally extensive offerings, like Publix or Wegmans for example, you may actually find a bit of a selection.  Some of these chains have chain-branded coffees (including decaf whole bean), which I've found to actually be pretty good (don't automatically assume that any store brand will be a budget alternative; they are sometimes better than the nationally-advertised item).